Configure nginx maintenance page with images/css and proxy
I've read a lot of questions about configuring nginx maintenance pages, but I can't figure out how to do this particular thing. Normally my nginx is just proxying everything to another service. For maintenance mode, I need it to return a maintenance.html page, but that page has images and css links. So the problem is if I 503 based on the existence of a file, it 503s all the images too. I can see how to avoid that without the proxy, but when not in maintenance mode, I need the images proxied too and I can't figure out how to do it. Essentially, I need this:
if maintenance mode
   if image or css -> send /var/www/html/image
   else -> send /var/www/html/maintenance.html
else
   proxy everything including images and css
end

The other answers I've read assume you want to always serve the images out of /var/www/html, but I only want to do that in maintenance mode. I've gotten this far, I just need to know how to handle the images.
  error_page 503 @maintenance;
  location @maintenance { 
    ### what goes here to prevent images from 503ing or returning maintenance.html
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /maintenance.html break;
  } 
  location / {
    if (-f /var/www/html/maintenance.html) {
      return 503;
    }
    proxy_pass...
  }

Thanks in advance.

Replace the rewrite statement with try_files $uri /maintenance.html;

Thanks, but that just returns a 503 for everything, including the maintenance.html page when in maintenance mode.

Replace the rewrite statement with try_files $uri /maintenance.html =404; (the final =404 is not reached, but allows the /maintenance.html term to be processed within the current location). Also, change the error_page statement to error_page 503 = @maintenance; which allows the response code to be changed from 503 to 200.

That did it, thanks.I had to change the image and css paths to be absolute (/style.css instead of style.css) to get nested folders to work correctly, but the config did the trick. I'll update the question with the full solution for future use.

I noticed that this also works: "try_files $uri /maintenance.html /;" or "try_files $uri /maintenance.html /whatever;" But I don't understand why that's different than "try_files $uri /maintenance.html;". Can you please explain what's going on?

See this link. The final parameter of a try_files statement is a response code, named location, or internal redirect. In order for /maintenance.html to be treated as a file parameter, it needs to be anywhere in the statement except last place. An internal redirect will just loop and end up serving a standard 503 error.
